# Add vendor/assets/javascripts to my valid assets route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to make this work but it's driving me mad. I already set this in

**application.rb**

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor", "assets", "javascripts").to_s
```

(.to_s because it returns an object while I want a string in here).
I cant find the solution and is driving me mad, because stylesheets directory in vendor works, but javascripts is not.

How can i do this?

**Error returned:**

```
<h1>Routing Error</h1>
<p><pre>No route matches [GET] &quot;/assets/ext-all-debug.js&quot;</pre></p>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe vendor is already included in your assets path, check using the rails console

```
rails console
Rails.application.config.assets.paths.each do |path|; puts path; end
```

However the easiest thing might be this

- put ext at app/assets/javascripts/lib
- require_tree will load it already or be explicit

application.js

```
//= require ./lib/ext-all-debug.js
```

If you really want it in vendor

- create dir vendor/assets/javascripts/ext
- create manifest file vendor/assets/javascripts/ext/index.js
- put ext-all-debug.js into vendor/assets/javascripts/ext/

code for index.js

```
//= require ./ext-all-debug.js
```

code for application.js

```
//= require ext
```

that is the name of the dir that the index manifest file is located

Restart your rails server

if you don't want to load extjs via application.js, i.e. you want to include the extjs lib only on specific pages

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "ext" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add:

```
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts
```

to your `application.js` file.

Answer (score 1):

**READ THE UPDATE**

It looks like the problem is connected to the fact that EXT has it's own structure path build with relative paths.

I solved the problem by preserving the whole ext directory structure as is (without splitting images anywhere) and I added it to a vendor/externals directory (created by me). I then added the path with:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor", "assets", "externals").to_s
```

And now everything it's working fine by referencing it with //= require ext-all-debug.js

**Update 23/12/2013:**

As of Rails 3, notice that this directory has been added by default.

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to see the problem from the information you've provided as I think that the problem is elsewhere.

The purporse of asset pipeline is to to put **all** javascripts into one file. And that file is included to the HTML document. So the key is that one big JS file. Well, it can be more complicated but I think that's not necessarily your case.

So for example in your layout ERB (typically `app/views/layout/application.erb`):

```
<head>
  ...
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
</head>
```

and in `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`:

```
//= require ext_all_debug
//= ...
```

When HTML page is requested, it asks for "application.js" and it is generated in a way that your vendor JS code is embedded into this file (notice that there is no path in that require).

And one last thing - it's quite important to test the behaviour in production environment because typically those generated JS files will be served by nginx/apache. `rake assets:precompile` is a good start.